# CAN data for Mahindra

Tags: obd

I bought a new Mahindra Scorpio S10 and have been trying to read the CAN bus using ELM 327 Bluetooth OBD and Putty.
Configurations in Putty: Baud Rate 9600 (tried 115200 also), Data bits: 10, Stop bits: 1

I have been getting data for mode 01 and PIDs like 0c (RPM), 0d (Speed) but I am not able to get data like distance travelled since fault code cleared (which I guess is locked by the manufacturer). I am sending the command 010c and getting the response 7E8 04 41 0c 0c 84

Moreover when I send 2132 command I get the VIN number (compared with 0902 command which gives the VIN). I started sending 2110,2111,2112,.....2199 and received data for a few commands (out of which 2130 and 2133 gave a bigger number of 34 and 36 bytes, seems to be some identification number).

Can someone please help me how can I decode the values I am getting. Is there any manual/website for Mahindra CAN data and its custom PIDs.

Comment: Try [Torque Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torque&hl=en) and see if you can get better values. It costs a couple of bucks, but I understand it's well worth it, especially where the ELM327 interface is concerned.